# How get values on legend label withn Chart js on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, angular-chart

How can get values of DataSet in legend label please with Chart js on Angular ?

In legend Like :

```
centre1    55
centre2    25
centre3    20
```

```
export class DoughnutChartComponent {

  doughnutChartLabels: Label[] = ['Centre1', 'Centre2', 'Centre3'];
  doughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [
    [55, 25, 20]
  ];
  doughnutChartOptions: ChartOptions = { legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'right',
      fullWidth:false,
      labels: {
        usePointStyle: true,
        boxWidth: 10,
        padding: 7,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontColor: '#003457',
        fontStyle: 'bold'
      },
      },
     cutoutPercentage: 70,
    };
  doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';
  doughnutChartColor: Colors[] = [{
    backgroundColor: [
      '#2E9FE0',
      '#9CCA32',
      '#255FCC',
    ]
  }] ;
}
```

I tried to add `legenTemplate` but don't working.

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

Make your labels array like this: `doughnutChartLabels: Label[] = ['Centre1 55', 'Centre2 25', 'Centre3 20'];`

Instead of doing it hardcoded like this you would need to do this in a loop beforehand